# Cargo command to print the list of target files?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

What is the command to get `cargo` to print the list of files it would output after running `cargo build`?

Comment: You also want all the files that `lib.rs` (or `main.rs`) includes using `mod ...;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`cargo read-manifest`](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/src/bin/read_manifest.rs) will print a JSON object that contains a `targets` key that you can use. Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to filter and pretty print, here's the output on a checkout of the `rustfmt` crate:

```
➜ cargo read-manifest | jq '.targets'
[
  {
    "kind": [
      "lib"
    ],
    "name": "rustfmt",
    "src_path": "/Users/.../rustfmt/src/lib.rs"
  },
  {
    "kind": [
      "bin"
    ],
    "name": "cargo-fmt",
    "src_path": "/Users/.../rustfmt/src/bin/cargo-fmt.rs"
  },
  {
    "kind": [
      "bin"
    ],
    "name": "rustfmt",
    "src_path": "/Users/.../rustfmt/src/bin/rustfmt.rs"
  },
  {
    "kind": [
      "custom-build"
    ],
    "name": "build-script-build",
    "src_path": "build.rs"
  },
  {
    "kind": [
      "test"
    ],
    "name": "system",
    "src_path": "/Users/.../rustfmt/tests/system.rs"
  }
]
```

Comment: As I understand it, the question is impossible to fully answer as [build scripts](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) are capable of outputting any files they want.

Comment: No .dylib, .exe or .so extensions included?